# Ошибка при добавлении новой записи в БД через Entity

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

Разбираюсь потихоньку с Entity. На этот раз проблема в добавлении записи в таблицу Mysql. Таблица :

```
CREATE TABLE `cashaccounts` (
`orderKlient` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`CA_USD` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
`CA_EUR` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
`CA_GBP` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
`CA_SGD` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
`CA_AUD` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
`CashAllocation` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
`DATEH` datetime NOT NULL
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Сущность в edmx (подход DataBaseFirst) :

```
 public partial class cashaccounts
 {
    public string orderKlient { get; set; }
    public decimal CA_USD { get; set; }
    public decimal CA_EUR { get; set; }
    public decimal CA_GBP { get; set; }
    public decimal CA_SGD { get; set; }
    public decimal CA_AUD { get; set; }
    public decimal CashAllocation { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DATEH { get; set; }
 }
```

И сам код, добавляющий новую строку в таблицу :

```
public void NewCashHistory()
    {
        var newRow = new cashaccounts();
        newRow.orderKlient = order;
        newRow.CashAllocation = cashallocation;
        newRow.CA_AUD = 11.22M;
        newRow.CA_EUR = 11.22M;
        newRow.CA_GBP = 11.22M;
        newRow.CA_SGD = 11.22M;
        newRow.CA_USD = 11.22M;
        newRow.DATEH = DateTime.Now;

        using (custodianhistoryEntities1 Context = new custodianhistoryEntities1())
        {
            Context.cashaccounts.Add(newRow);
            Context.SaveChanges();  // тут ошибка
        };
    }
```

При попытке сохранить изменения вылетает ошибка :

> Необработанное исключение типа "System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException" в EntityFramework.dll
>
> Дополнительные сведения: При обновлении записей возникла ошибка. Дополнительные сведения приведены во внутреннем исключении.

Подозреваю что дело в формате даты, так ил это? Кто сталкивался, подскажите как исправить?

Больше сведений об исключении :

> StackTrace:
>               в System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
>               в System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.b__2(UpdateTranslator ut)
>               в System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update[T](T noChangesResult, Func`2 updateFunction)
>               в System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update()
>               в System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<SaveChangesToStore>b__35()
>               в System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
>               в System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction)
>               в System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass2a.b__27()
>               в System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
>               в System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal(SaveOptions options, Boolean executeInExistingTransaction)
>               в System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
>               в System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
>          InnerException: 
>               ErrorCode=-2147467259
>               HResult=-2147467259
>               Message=You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT`
>   cashaccounts`.`orderKlient`,`
>   cashaccounts`.`CA_USD`,`
>   cashaccounts`.' at line 1
>               Number=1064
>               Source=MySql.Data

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65238/discussion-on-question-by----------e).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я работал с Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore и [Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql).

1) Создал обычный консольный проект.

2) Открыл Package Manager Console и установил нужные пакеты

`PM> Install-Package Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql`

`PM> Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools`

`PM> Install-Package Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Design`

3) И когда я попытался сделать скефолдинг получил жалобу на отсутствие первичного ключа
 `PM> Scaffold-DbContext "Server=localhost;User Id=root;Password=1234;Database=test_schema" Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql -OutputDir Models`

`Unable to identify the primary key for table 'cashaccounts'.
rosoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.RelationalScaffoldingModelFactory[7]
      Unable to identify the primary key for table 'cashaccounts'.`

4) добавил первичный ключ в вашу таблицу

5) делаю скефолдинг

`PM> Scaffold-DbContext "Server=localhost;User Id=root;Password=1234;Database=test_schema" Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql -OutputDir Models -Force`

6) в папке Models создается класс сущности

```
public partial class Cashaccounts
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal CaAud { get; set; }
    public decimal CaEur { get; set; }
    public decimal CaGbp { get; set; }
    public decimal CaSgd { get; set; }
    public decimal CaUsd { get; set; }
    public decimal CashAllocation { get; set; }
    public DateTime Dateh { get; set; }
    public string OrderKlient { get; set; }
}
```

и такой вот класс контекста

```
public partial class test_schemaContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Cashaccounts> Cashaccounts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseMySql(@"Server=localhost;User Id=root;Password=1234;Database=test_schema");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Cashaccounts>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("cashaccounts");

            entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnType("mediumint(9)");

            entity.Property(e => e.CaAud)
                .HasColumnName("CA_AUD")
                .HasColumnType("decimal(10,2)");

            entity.Property(e => e.CaEur)
                .HasColumnName("CA_EUR")
                .HasColumnType("decimal(10,2)");

            entity.Property(e => e.CaGbp)
                .HasColumnName("CA_GBP")
                .HasColumnType("decimal(10,2)");

            entity.Property(e => e.CaSgd)
                .HasColumnName("CA_SGD")
                .HasColumnType("decimal(10,2)");

            entity.Property(e => e.CaUsd)
                .HasColumnName("CA_USD")
                .HasColumnType("decimal(10,2)");

            entity.Property(e => e.CashAllocation).HasColumnType("decimal(10,2)");

            entity.Property(e => e.Dateh)
                .HasColumnName("DATEH")
                .HasColumnType("datetime");

            entity.Property(e => e.OrderKlient)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasColumnName("orderKlient")
                .HasColumnType("varchar(45)");
        });
    }
}
```

Ну, а дальше дело техники

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ConsoleTest1");

        using (test_schemaContext context = new test_schemaContext())
        {
            //AddAccount(context);

            ShowAccounts(context);
        };

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void AddAccount(test_schemaContext context)
    {
        var newRow = new Cashaccounts();
        newRow.CaAud = 11.22M;
        newRow.CaEur = 11.22M;
        newRow.CaGbp = 11.22M;
        newRow.CaSgd = 11.22M;
        newRow.CaUsd = 11.22M;
        newRow.Dateh = DateTime.Now;
        newRow.CashAllocation = 11.22M;
        newRow.OrderKlient = "TestClient";

        context.Cashaccounts.Add(newRow);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    private static void ShowAccounts(test_schemaContext context)
    {
        var accs = context.Cashaccounts.ToList();

        accs.ForEach(a => Console.WriteLine($"{a.Id}-{a.OrderKlient}:{a.Dateh}"));
    }

}
```

И вуаля все работает.

Comment: Благодарю. Буду разбираться !

Comment: @Сергей Пара необходимых ссылок : [Entity Framework Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/) и [Learn Entity Framework Core](http://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/), желаю успехов.